# Access mdb password recovery

Tags: ms-access

I was searching a lot of time for definition of the mdb (Access) database structure, but I haven't found anything about password recovery.

I know that Access 2000 mdb file has sth like pages, 4kB for every page, every page has a type and the first page is a "*Database definition page*" containing (probably) a encrypted database password.

There is a lot of software able to read MS Access db password, so I think it is not secret where the password is stored.

Where/how can the Access password be found?

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html works great

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Jet 3:** The database password, when set, is stored as plain text in the MDB file header.

**Jet 4:** The database password, when set, is obfuscated with a simple XOR pattern algorithm based on the file creation date/time (stored inside the file) which is then stored in the MDB file header.

**Jet 3 AND 4:** The MDB file header itself is further obfuscated with an XOR pattern – although its a constant XOR stream this time.

**ACCDB Files:** The password is no longer stored as obfuscated plain text in the file header.  Instead, a hash is used to check that the user has entered the valid password.  The hash is generated from a combination of RC4 and SHA-1 algorithms.

Comment: Very interesting but I still haven't found specification about the header. In which part of it the password is stored (index, length etc.). No source code available.

Comment: @daftu - that's a dead link you posted. Can you fix it. I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was ULS restricting access to the .mdb.

This codeproject link allowed me to read the database in .NET: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283626/MsAccess-MdbTools-with-MFC-and-NET

Answer (score 0):

According to the webpage mentioned below, the tools don't actually look up a password from the MDB file but bombard the database with a list of possible passwords until successful.

Quote from the webpage:

> These software employ brute force attack technique to recover the lost password accurately and precisely. They maintain a dynamic dictionary, which stores all the recovered passwords. They recover Access password by searching this dictionary and then applying the brute force technique. This helps to considerably reduce the password recovery time.

[Click here for the full page](http://windowspassword.org/tag/mdb/)

Comment: You're wrong. Every software I've tested recovered even very complicated password in about 1ms so the brute-force method couldn't be used. I'm sure the password is stored in some part of mdb file and easy to read.

Comment: Okay the webpage may well be wrong but I did not say I agreed with it…