# How can I recover a password of Microsoft Jet DB?

Tags: ms-access

I have a very old software (2004) that was used for accounting and finance for my Dad's business. I'm able to login with the software but I don't to the password of the Jet Database. Any ideas on how can I get access to it?

Or can the software be reverse engineered to find the password ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you if it's a *.mdb file: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html

Comment: see this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764264/access-mdb-password-recovery